# router-outlet is not a known element

Tags: angular2-routing

The following code works:

```
/*app.module.ts*/
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LetterRecall } from './letterRecall/letterRecall.component';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [BrowserModule, HttpModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, LetterRecall],
    bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}

/*app.component.ts*/
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { }

/*app.component.html*/
<h3>Title</h3>
<letter-recall></letter-recall>
```

---

Following the Angular Routing Tutorial here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html

I modified my code to:

```
/*index.html*/
<head>
   <base href="/">

/*app.module.ts*/
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LetterRecall } from './letterRecall/letterRecall.component';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [BrowserModule, 
                   HttpModule,
                   RouterModule.forRoot([
                       { path: 'letters', component: LetterRecall }
                   ])],
    declarations: [AppComponent, LetterRecall],
    bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}

/*app.component.ts*/
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { }

/*app.component.html*/
<h3>Title</h3>
<a routerLink="/letters">Letters</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

At this point I get the following error:

> "Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: 'router-outlet'
>   is not a known element:
>   1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. ....."

I am using the following versions:

```
    "@angular/common": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.0"
```

---

All of the other answers on SO indicate I need to import RouterModule but as you can see above, I am doing this as prescribed in the tutorial.

Any suggestions on where I can look for the source of this error? I started off using John Papa's First Look tutorial on PluralSight but it looks like that code is a little old now. That's when I stripped all of that out and went bare-bones through the tutorial and I get this error... I am not sure where to turn next.

Comment: Try to import all dependencies of router.

Comment: So I stashed that branch and started over. The only change (that I can find) is that I updated the version of zone.js from 0.6.23 to 0.7.2. I don't think this is related but...it now works. 

I may go back to that stash and try your suggestion but at this point I think I may chalk this one up to gremlins.

Comment: You may also should look here https://angular.io/guide/testing form more information about set up the testing environment for Angular

Answer (score 29):

Like Erion said: In my case I did (added) two things in app.component.spec.ts:

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
...
TestBed.configureTestingModule({ 
  imports: [ RouterTestingModule ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
}).compileComponents();
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably I'm late here, but since I got the exaclty same issue and found an answer here.

Are you using angular-cli?
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/3252/files#diff-badc0de0550cb14f40374a6074eb2a8b

In my case I just had to import my new router module in the app.component.spec.ts
The js import and NgModule import.

Then restart the test server.

Comment: I did the same, but browser console, still showing error. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

The angular router directive is part of part of lib: @angular/router and it acts a placeholder which is filled up by angular state.

Here I am dividing two file separately i.e. app.module.ts and app.router.ts

Here app.router.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MainComponent } from './components/main/main.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main', component: MainComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/main', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRouter { }
```

Here app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRouter } from './app.router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MainComponent } from './components/main/main.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRouter
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now you can use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your app.component.ts file and won't show any error